# how much memory to be allocated to "events" pointer in epoll_wait

Tags: c, linux, epoll

I'm trying to understand the "events" pointer in epoll_wait. When epoll_wait returns, does this pointer point to some memory (not allocated by the user) where all the events structures are present? Or do we have to allocate memory to this pointer and then pass the pointer so that the events will get filled up in that memory location?

If memory has to be allocated, then how much should be allocated? Let's say I want to do an epoll_wait on 10,000 sockets. All of them are to be checked for data to be read (EPOLLIIN). So, should I allocate memory equivalent to 10,000 event structures to *events?

Thanks,

VSN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at the example in e.g. the [epoll(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/epoll) manual page? You need to provide the actual event array, either as a proper array as in the example, or by allocating of the heap (and freeing it later).

Comment: I didn't see that one... I was looking at another "http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/epoll_wait.2.html". So that means, I have to give as many event structures (either as an array or memory on the heap) as the number of sockets that I would be "epoll_wait"-ing on. Right?

Comment: I thought MAXEVENTS was the number of events that I'm expecting to be set. For instance, EPOLLIN is one event, EPOLLOUT is another. Am I wrong?

Comment: @VSN Regarding your first question, yes that's correct. Come to think about it, I once made a server with epoll events "array" that was reallocated every time a client connected/disconnected. Don't have any code left though. Regarding your second question, I don't remember. It is a bitfield, so you could get two events in one event structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Really helped. Yes, turns out that maxevents has to be the number of sockets that you expect to be set where the bitfield will indicate more than one event (EPOLLIN, EPOLLOUT etc.) Also, your answer was corroborated by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2969425/epoll-wait-maxevents?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

MaxEvents is how big your array is in elements. If you allocate memory that is `sizeof(epoll_event) * 10`, then `maxEvents` is 10. MaxEvents is unrelated to the number of sockets you are listening on.